# How to avoid extra header bytes while writing a file in Java?

Tags: java, file, io, stream

Firstly, I am not using *high-level* default serialization of Java to write an object in a file. I am *manually* writing some primitive type variables in a file. Here is the example:

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Test.bin")));

            out.writeInt(1024);
            out.writeInt(512);
            out.writeInt(256);
            out.writeInt(128);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have tested the created file "Test.bin". The filesize is *22 bytes*. But calculating what I have actually written in the file, the filesize should be *16 bytes*. [`int` is 4 bytes each. 4 `int` variables. So 4 * 4 = 16 bytes.]

So what is the extra *6 bytes*? [22 - 16 = 6 bytes] I have tested the file with a hex editor. That is what I have found:

> **ac ed 20 05 77 10** 20 20 04 20 20 20 02 20 20 20 01 20 20 20 20 80

I have tested more files with different codes. I have found that the first 5 bytes of the files are exactly same. The 6th byte represents the *actual size* what the file should be. In this example, it is `10` in hex, which is decimal 16 - that is correct.

Now, my question is how to avoid these bytes in Java? Why are they saved even for primitive types? My real application still has explicit header info for version compatibility purpose. I do not need the extra bytes from Java for any purposes. Though it is *6 bytes*, it is simply a waste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

> Primitive data, excluding serializable fields and externalizable data, is written to the ObjectOutputStream in block-data records. A block data record is composed of a header and data. The block data header consists of a marker and the number of bytes to follow the header. Consecutive primitive data writes are merged into one block-data record. The blocking factor used for a block-data record will be 1024 bytes. Each block-data record will be filled up to 1024 bytes, or be written whenever there is a termination of block-data mode. Calls to the ObjectOutputStream methods writeObject, defaultWriteObject and writeFields initially terminate any existing block-data record.

If you only want to write `byte`s, use a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).

Comment: Then I have to manually implement `readInt`, `readDouble`, etc methods? Is it correct?

Comment: You need *some* metadata unless all elements have fixed width.

Comment: I can also avoid metadata even for all elements having fixed width by *serially* reading and writing. I have understood that I have to implement `writeInt`, `writeDouble`, etc methods because `FileOutputStream` only supports `byte` and `byte []`.

Comment: Instead of using `FileOutputStream`, I think, I should use `BufferedOutputStream` for performance reason.

Comment: Use DataInput/OutputStream chained with FileInput/OutputStream to get methods for reading and writing primitives as binary data. Add a BufferedInput/OutputStream if you want as well.