# ObjectOutputStream.writeBytes(String s) unexpected output values

Tags: java, android, objectoutputstream

I am using an `ObjectOutputStream` object os to send a String msg from a client Android app to a c++ server.

I know how my msg must be received by the server: 
each char of the msg is stored in a byte array (received_msg[]). I also know the exact msg the server expects (through another c++ app).

The data I send is a string made from 1 byte array and 2 other string.

My problem: 
I already used `PrintWriter` to send my data, but my server would always display some weird char in `received_msg`, at index 24 to 28.
I tried a lot of conversions to fix it, but gave up on that.
So I tried sending msg with  `ObjectOutputStream`. 
With the client using `ObjectOutputStream.writeBytes()`, the server shows almost the right received message. Almost because there are characters that are added at the beginning.

Something like that :
In the server received_msg:

```
index 0: ┐

index 1: i

index 2: ''

index 3: |

index 4: I //beginning of the message I actually wanted to send

index 5: S //every char following index 4 is good.
```

while I expected and sent nothing before 'I''S'. 
The message I send begins like that : ISOXXXXX

So I was wondering if there were any ways to retrieve the REAL output of  ObjectOutputStream.writeBytes. I know that it's Output, not Input, still that would help me understand how it adds the weird header.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion

My send function

```
private void send(String o) {
    System.out.println("socket");
    try {
        this.socket = new Socket(serverIP, portNumber);
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        //OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        //InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        // PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);

        System.out.println("Connected to server : " + this.socket.getInetAddress() + " on port " + this.socket.getPort());
        System.out.println("from local address: " + this.socket.getLocalAddress() + " and port: " + this.socket.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("02. -> Sending an object...");

        ArrayList<String>  tempoStr = StringToByteArray(o);
        String msg="";
        for(String inStr :tempoStr)
             msg+=inStr;
        System.out.println("the message I ACTUALLY send is\n"+msg); //the result in console is EXACTLY the message I expect.
        os.writeBytes(msg); //then when I check on the server:  unexpected additionnal chars at the beginning.
        os.flush();
       // pw.write(msg);
       //pw.flush();
        System.out.println("send success");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("XX. Exception Occurred on Sending:" +  e.toString() +"\n"+ e.getCause());
        System.out.println("Socket creation failure or error on sending.");

    }
}
```

PS: I cannot change the server code.

Comment: OOS's .writeString() will write modified UTF, this is certainly not what you want. Also, what is the encoding? ASCII?

Comment: *An ObjectOutputStream writes primitive data types and graphs of Java objects to an OutputStream*

Comment: I use ASCII encoding.  
The message i send is : msg = "ISOxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp ������ÀXXXXXX��&XXXXXXX", where X's are numbers. 
I just want to send it like that to the server. And the server receives it fully, but seem to add  other characters  at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use ObjectOutputStream (java only). One might use DataOutputStream, but here it seems you want something simple.

```
byte[] a = ...
String b = ...

OutputStream out = ...
out.write(a);
out.write((b + '\u0000').getBytes("UTF-8")); // Or "Windows-1252" / "ISO-8859-1"
out.flush();
```

I have added a `'\0'` as that is used in C/C++ to terminate strings (**binary output**).
Or maybe `"\r\n"` might be expected (**text output**).

The encoding is given explicitly.

Comment: I found this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583168/how-to-avoid-extra-header-bytes-while-writing-a-file-in-java.

They say: "Primitive data, excluding serializable fields and externalizable data, is written to the ObjectOutputStream in block-data records. A block data record is composed of a header and data. The block data header consists of a marker and the number of bytes to follow the header. "

I think what i need is to get rid of the header

Comment: The advise there is also to use a `(File)OutputStream` instead - that is: write the raw bytes directly. From your comments it seems that the bytes part are also text? Text in java is internally in Unicode, so to get bytes in some encoding X, one needs to specify X, or inversely to get a text String from bytes, better specify their encoding.

Comment: I tried your solution Joop Eggen, but I still have the header.  I will try   DataInput/OutputStream chained with FileInput/OutputStream.
I already wasted a lot of time on trying to write raw bytes, and I would prefer sending the string...

Comment: IMHO DataInput/OutputStream will bring no solution faster. Dump the bytes in numerical form, check where they come from.

Comment: It's all ASCII encoded. Yes, the byte part is also text. it's just that this part changes when I change the way I write (PrinterWrite, ObjectOutputStream.writeBytes,... each has a different result on the text from the byte part). And I found that with ObjectOutputStream.writeBytes, the message is received with the characters I want it to be ... and with an additionnal header

Comment: A hack for those bytes might shed some light: `write(new String(a, "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"))`. As `writeBytes` treats a `char` (text, 2 bytes UTF-16) as a `byte`.